# Android mapsforge mapView.projection.toPixels error

Tags: android, geolocation, android-mapview, mapsforge

On images is shown geo position of the cross-road (pink dot):

[image: image #1]

[image: image #2]

Proper position of the pink dot is written in right-down corner of images, in white rectangle.

Inside mapsforge MapView activity, using:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(nMotionEvent ev) 
{   int xpos = (int)ev.getX();
    int ypos = (int)ev.getY();

    Projection pr = mapView.getProjection();
    GeoPoint g = pr.fromPixels(xpos, ypos);

    ...
}
```

position of the pink dot is shown in black *Toast*.

It's different from the proper position, and change after set another zoom level.

Is this error in mapsforge MapView fromPixels or I do it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Enviroment must migrate from mapsforge library **0.3.0** to **0.4.0**.
In 0.4.0 transformation from lat/lon to screen pixels position is calculated OK.